# Xamarin Forms Navigation Transitions

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, android-transitions

I just re-used Rg.Plugins.Popup code for navigation transitions/animations between content pages to avoid default (buggy) navigation in android. It's working good but the thing is that I could not get the navigation bar working (actually it is missing). Is there anyway to make it work like default navigation bars? (with back icon, page title, etc).

Comment: Can you please show some code? Did you use `NavigationPage` or did you make your own navigation?

Comment: Refer this code https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/blob/master/src/Rg.Plugins.Popup/Extensions/NavigationExtension.cs

Comment: Still didn't see any of your code, problem is that in XF, the `NavigationBar` will be shown if the root page of your app is a `NavigationPage`, I checked the demo of this plugin you used, he actually used 
 `NavigationPage`, then the navigation bar works fine by my side. Did you try the demo of this plugin?

Comment: Yes. I could see the bar in main page but not with the navigated pages. Here is the derived class which I used to create my pages. https://gist.github.com/MuruganDurai/833ed546b1063fde368a9c3966df59ec . This page is same as the https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/blob/master/src/Rg.Plugins.Popup/Pages/PopupPage.cs with popup related methods removed.

Comment: I think the problem is that you used its `PopupNavigation` for navigation, not the original `Navigation` of `NavigationPage`, as we know, `NavigationPage` has its renderer in each platform, it's like a custom control made by XF officially, only the `PopupNavigation` of this plugin didn't interact together with the `Navigation` of `NavigationPage`, it do listen to the back button of system, as you can see here [PopupNavigationDroid](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/blob/a0bfde7409b540e8627edb0efda31692b0ca1994/src/Rg.Plugins.Popup.Droid/Impl/PopupNavigationDroid.cs).

Comment: Even in our code we call `await Navigation.PushPopupAsync(page);` for navigation, it actually `return PopupNavigation.PushAsync(page, animate);`. So, I think it is designed so by this plugin. Unless you used the official method like `this.Navigation.PushAsync(page, true);`

Comment: Thanks @GraceFeng-MSFT . Don't want to rewrite the NavigationPage. Do you guys have any plugin/code for navigation transitions/animations which would easily fix the navigation transitions effects?

Comment: No, what kind of animation do you want to achieve?

Comment: Simple Slide animations with Left/Right/Top/Bottom during navigation.